# python communication between different classes and .py files

Tags: python, wxpython, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to use the mvc-model in my program. I use pubsub to communicate between my files. I was wondering if there is another way to communicate instead of using pubsub?

My specific problem: I have 2 files. In file 1 I have a if-structure, where it needs information from file 2. Frame A must be opened if a certain panel is hidden in frame B, or frame A can't open if the panel is visible in frame B.

I could send a pubsub message from file 1 to file 2 to ask if the panel is hidden, then file 2 could send a message back with the answer. But is this the most efficient way?

Tx

EDIT: I use wxpython and I'm using the pubsub library as explained here: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

EDIT 2: I 'solved' the problem with the pubsub way. But I still wonder if this is the best way. My code:

file 1: browser_menubar_view.py:

```
pub.subscribe(self.on_status_MA_panel, "RETURN_STATUS_MA_PANEL")
def on_open_microanalysis(self, event):
    #check if MA panel view is hidden or not. If hidden, MA frame may open, if not, MA frame must be closed
    #send message to choosepanel to see if ma_panel_view is hidden or not
    pub.sendMessage("STATUS_MA_PANEL") #to choosePanel_view.py
    if self.statusMAPanelShown == False:
        pub.sendMessage("Unhide_MA_With_question") #to microanalyse_view
    else:
        wx.MessageBox('Microanalysis is already open in filterview.', 'Info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
```

file 2: choosePanel_view.py

```
pub.subscribe(self.on_status_MA_panel, "STATUS_MA_PANEL")
def on_status_MA_panel(self,message):
    if self.MApanel.IsShown() == True:
        self.statusMAPanelShown = True
    else:
        self.statusMAPanelShown = False
    pub.sendMessage("RETURN_STATUS_MA_PANEL",Container(data=self.statusMAPanelShown)) #to browser_MB_view
```

Comment: pubsub? Which library/tool are you using for this? Panels? are you using a gui framework/library? I guess you need more tags to your question so people can have a better idea. "communicating between files" sounds weird - what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: there is no such thing as "pubsub message", what is there is a message that gets published to multiple subscribers, as per the scenario you explained publish-subscribe is not what you want, what you want is processes intermessaging(or threads depending on what you mean by "Frame A" and "Frame B")

Comment: I will look into 'threads' to see if it is efficienter than pub.sendmessage() . tx.

Comment: I do not recommend you to look into threads for this kind of task. Sounds like you're having a problem to solve, then with threads you have 2 problems ! At least, please show us some code so we can give you a better advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things that I recommend:

1) Design of sender vs receiver

In a pubsub architecture, components never ask info from other components, because this would violate the publish-subscribe's principle of anonymity: you must design your app so that publishers know nothing of their listeners, and listeners know nothing of the publishers. At most, each side knows what messages are available, with what payload.

So in pubsub, if A must do something only if B is in a certain state, and you want to decouple A and B via pub-sub pattern, then A does not ask B what its state is, but rather, B publishes its state whenever it changes. If no component is interested in B's state, B does not care, and does not know.

So in your app, have B publish what its state is:

```
# B file: 
pub.sendMessage('certain panel state', hidden=state)

# A file: 
def listener(hidden):
    print(hidden)
pub.subscribe(listener, 'certain panel state')
```

2) Design of message topics

I also recommend abstracting the topic name to be something user-centric rather than GUI-implementation centric. Here, the panel hidden in B is an implementation detail of B, which A should not know about. However, this panel of B certain has a purpose, such as allowing the user to enter some information, or perhaps the panel is only shown if the user has selected some option like "simple" vs "advanced", or if the user has items in their purchase cart. The topic should be named after the user-centered purpose of the panel in B, not after the GUI implementation component that the topic pertains to, so you would use instead

```
# B file: 
pub.sendMessage('cart_state', cart_empty=cart.is_empty) # example

# A file: 
def listener(cart_empty: bool):
    print(cart_empty)
pub.subscribe(listener, 'cart_state')
```

3) Version of pypubsub

Finally, ensure you are using the latest pubsub from https://github.com/schollii/pypubsub (yes, it used to be at sourceforge.net). The version of pypubsub that is included with wxPython is a little old (I'm still in the process of getting wxPython updated to use it), but pypubsub is actually its own separate project that can be installed very easily and separately from wxPython. If you find any bugs, post on pypubsub's github page, or in the pypubsub forum (see http://pypubsub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). If you are still using python 2.x, you are limited to pypubsub 3.3 and I highly recommend you upgrade to python 3.